# ReactJS dropdown select

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

I'm having a problem with the select section in reactjs.

So, when the user clicks on the category name in the dropdown, data will appear based on the category that was clicked.

For example, **a user clicks on the "Shopping" category, the "total_poi_belanja" data will appear below.**

However, when I make it, it appears instead as shown in the picture.

Help me to fix my code sir, thank you

[image]

The Endpoints : https://run.mocky.io/v3/07d87622-1431-4b55-86e5-9927ed51c773

My Code :

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionItemHeading,
  AccordionItemButton,
  AccordionItemPanel,
} from "react-accessible-accordion";
import { MdKeyboardArrowDown } from "react-icons/md";
import {
  getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi,
  getCountPoiCategoryKota,
  getCountPoiCategoryKecamatan,
  getCountPoiCategoryKelurahan,
} from "../../../service/poi";
import SearchComponent from "./SearchPoi";

const defaultSelectValue = "Select Category";

const listOfCategory = [
  { Label: "Agama", value: "total_poi_agama" },
  {
    Label: "Alam Terbuka & Rekreasi",
    value: "total_poi_alam_terbuka_dan_rekreasi",
  },
  { Label: "Area Pemukiman", value: "total_poi_area_pemukiman" },
  { Label: "Belanja", value: "total_poi_belanja" },
  { Label: "Hotel & Penginapan", value: "total_poi_hotel_dan_penginapan" },
  { Label: "Layanan", value: "total_poi_layanan" },
  { Label: "Makanan & Minuman", value: "total_poi_makanan_dan_minuman" },
  { Label: "Pendidikan", value: "total_poi_pendidikan" },
  {
    Label: "Perkantoran & Industri",
    value: "total_poi_perkantoran_dan_industri",
  },
  { Label: "Tempat", value: "total_poi_tempat" },
];

const PoiComp = () => {
  const [filterdata, setFilterdata] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [dataProvinsi, setDataProvinsi] = useState([]);
  const [dataKota, setDataKota] = useState([]);
  const [dataKecamatan, setDataKecamatan] = useState([]);
  const [dataKelurahan, setDataKelurahan] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingKota, setIsLoadingKota] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingKecamatan, setIsLoadingKecamatan] = useState(false);

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(defaultSelectValue);

  const provinsiRef = useRef([]);
  const kotaRef = useRef([]);
  const kecamatanRef = useRef([]);

  const getDataAllProvinsi = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getCountPoiCategoryProvinsi()
      .then((resolve) => {
        setDataProvinsi(resolve);
        setFilterdata(resolve);
        console.log(resolve);
      })
      .catch((reject) => {
        console.log(reject);
      })
      .finally(setIsLoading(false));
  };

  const handlesearch = (event) => {
    const getSearch = event.target.value;
    if (getSearch.length > 0) {
      const searchdata = dataProvinsi.filter((item) =>
        item.provinsi.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
      setDataProvinsi(searchdata);
    } else {
      setDataProvinsi(filterdata);
    }
    setQuery(getSearch);
  };

  const handleProvinsi = async (index) => {
    try {
      const provinsi = provinsiRef.current[index].dataset.prov;
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await getCountPoiCategoryKota(provinsi);
      setDataKota(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleKota = async (provinsi, index) => {
    try {
      const kota = kotaRef.current[index].dataset.city;
      setIsLoadingKota(true);
      const result = await getCountPoiCategoryKecamatan(provinsi, kota);
      setDataKecamatan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingKota(false);
    }
  };

  const handleKecamatan = async (provinsi, kota, index) => {
    try {
      const kecamatan = kecamatanRef.current[index].dataset.camat;
      setIsLoadingKecamatan(true);
      const result = await getCountPoiCategoryKelurahan(
        provinsi,
        kota,
        kecamatan
      );
      setDataKelurahan(result);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("salah");
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingKecamatan(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataAllProvinsi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto my-8 w-[70rem] bg-white px-5 py-3 md:px-8 md:py-5 rounded-md drop-shadow-xl">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        <SearchComponent value={query} onChange={(e) => handlesearch(e)} />
        <select
          id="show"
          className="form-select appearance-none block w-72 px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding bg-no-repeat border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
          defaultValue={selectedValue}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedValue(e.target.value)}
        >
          {listOfCategory.map((option, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={option.value}>
              {option.Label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-between mt-6">
        <h3 className="font-bold">Nama Daerah</h3>
        <h3 className="font-bold">TOTAL POI</h3>
      </div>
      <Accordion allowZeroExpanded>
        {dataProvinsi.map((provinsi, index) => (
          <AccordionItem className="p-1" key={index}>
            <AccordionItemHeading
              onClick={() => {
                handleProvinsi(index);
              }}
            >
              <AccordionItemButton>
                <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                  <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                    <div>
                      <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      ref={(ref) => provinsiRef.current.push(ref)}
                      data-prov={provinsi?.provinsi}
                    >
                      {provinsi?.provinsi}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>{selectedValue}</div>
                </div>
              </AccordionItemButton>
            </AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-4">
              <Accordion className="flex flex-col gap-2" allowZeroExpanded>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <div role="status">
                    <svg
                      class="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                      viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                      fill="none"
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                      <path
                        d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                        fill="currentColor"
                      />
                      <path
                        d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                        fill="currentFill"
                      />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  dataKota.map((kota, index) => (
                    <AccordionItem className="p-1" key={kota?.id}>
                      <AccordionItemHeading
                        onClick={() => {
                          handleKota(provinsi?.provinsi, index);
                        }}
                      >
                        <AccordionItemButton>
                          <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                            <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                              <div>
                                <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                              </div>
                              <div
                                ref={(ref) => kotaRef.current.push(ref)}
                                data-city={kota?.kota}
                              >
                                {kota?.kota}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>{kota?.total_street}</div>
                          </div>
                        </AccordionItemButton>
                      </AccordionItemHeading>
                      <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-8">
                        <Accordion
                          className="flex flex-col gap-2"
                          allowZeroExpanded
                        >
                          {isLoadingKota ? (
                            <div role="status">
                              <svg
                                class="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                                viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                                fill="none"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              >
                                <path
                                  d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                                  fill="currentColor"
                                />
                                <path
                                  d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                                  fill="currentFill"
                                />
                              </svg>
                              <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                            </div>
                          ) : (
                            dataKecamatan.map((kecamatan, index) => (
                              <AccordionItem
                                className="p-1"
                                key={kecamatan?.id}
                              >
                                <AccordionItemHeading
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    handleKecamatan(
                                      provinsi?.provinsi,
                                      kota?.kota,
                                      index
                                    );
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <AccordionItemButton>
                                    <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                                      <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                                        <div>
                                          <MdKeyboardArrowDown size={20} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                          ref={(ref) =>
                                            kecamatanRef.current.push(ref)
                                          }
                                          data-camat={kecamatan?.kecamatan}
                                        >
                                          {kecamatan?.kecamatan}
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div>{kecamatan?.total_street}</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </AccordionItemButton>
                                </AccordionItemHeading>
                                <AccordionItemPanel className="ml-12">
                                  <Accordion
                                    className="flex flex-col gap-2"
                                    allowZeroExpanded
                                  >
                                    {isLoadingKecamatan ? (
                                      <div role="status">
                                        <svg
                                          class="inline mr-2 w-8 h-8 text-gray-200 animate-spin dark:text-gray-600 fill-red-600"
                                          viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                                          fill="none"
                                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        >
                                          <path
                                            d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                                            fill="currentColor"
                                          />
                                          <path
                                            d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                                            fill="currentFill"
                                          />
                                        </svg>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                      </div>
                                    ) : (
                                      dataKelurahan.map((item, index) => (
                                        <AccordionItem
                                          className="p-1"
                                          key={index}
                                        >
                                          <AccordionItemHeading>
                                            <AccordionItemButton>
                                              <div className="w-full inline-flex justify-between items-center">
                                                <div className="inline-flex items-center gap-2">
                                                  <div>
                                                    <MdKeyboardArrowDown
                                                      size={20}
                                                    />
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div>{item?.kelurahan}</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>{item?.total_street}</div>
                                              </div>
                                            </AccordionItemButton>
                                          </AccordionItemHeading>
                                        </AccordionItem>
                                      ))
                                    )}
                                  </Accordion>
                                </AccordionItemPanel>
                              </AccordionItem>
                            ))
                          )}
                        </Accordion>
                      </AccordionItemPanel>
                    </AccordionItem>
                  ))
                )}
              </Accordion>
            </AccordionItemPanel>
          </AccordionItem>
        ))}
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PoiComp;
```

Comment: what is the expected output ? can you update any sample

Comment: @Arjun see my comments in another section

Answer (score 0):

@Arjun like this

[image]

So, when the user selects the menu in the dropdown, it will display data that matches the value in the dropdown.

Comment: It seems in your code you are displaying `<div>{selectedValue}</div>` here selected value is the listOfCategory value. instead you want to display the commented code `<div>{provinsi?.total_poi_agama}</div>` ?

Comment: <div>{provinsi?.total_poi_agama}</div> is my previous code, it only shows "total_poi_agama" data only.

Comment: No i think. What you have currently is displaying the `selectedValue` which is nothing but your dropdown value for ex: `total_poi_hotel_dan_penginapan`.

Comment: oh okay, so do you have a solution to fix this?
because I'm very confused about displaying the data "total_poi_agama",
"total_poi_alam_terbuka_dan_rekreasi",
"total_poi_area_pemukiman"
and others

Comment: try this `<div>{provinsi && provinsi[selectedValue]}</div>`